# Transferring files between Android and PC via Wi-Fi Direct

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, android, file-transfer

I want to use Wi-Fi Direct to transfer files between Android and PC. I do not want to use any third-party software, not even the free versions. I want to fully use the Wi-Fi Direct technology via command line or ad-hoc network.

How can I do that?

Comment: AFAIK - no way.

Comment: does https://www.justbeamit.com/ count as third party software?

Comment: Can ADB not be run over wifi direct?

Answer (score 1):

In layman's terms, natively Android can not be mounted via WLAN as a "drive", neither does Android natively offer something like a "network folder" (or can access it on another system). So either you use a different connection (e.g. a USB cable) or third party software.

There might be some "third party" tools from your phone's manufacturer but that depends...

Comment: Reasonable answer, but there are tools available for this. I use **andSMB** from the Google play store for this exact use. It doesn't have the server function that I know of, but can connect to samba share as a client just fine.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart who developed andSMB? The OP doesn't want to use any "third party software"...

Comment: I saw, it is why I said this is a reasonable answer, and upvoted It. would be nice if this was offered in the development section options in android settings to turn it on and off. I'm sure they excluded it because of the security concerns of having it natively in the OS. Lol but I still want the option to turn it on and off.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart yeah, I agree...

Answer (score 1):

Here is an app for you [**WiFi File Transfer**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smarterdroid.wififiletransfer&hl=en_US&gl=US).

Comment: Note the OP's requirement: "I do not want to use any third-party software, not even the free versions."

Comment: @Albin That is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

smarterdroid's Wifi File Transfer enables communication between PC and android. **you must have some kind of server running** on the android device in order to talk to it with shell commands such as wget and curl.